# reverse proof of sin30 = 1/2 without trigonometry

Tags: triangles, angle

The length of one side of the right triangle (AB) in the picture is half of the length of the hypotenuse (AC).

How can I prove that $\angle ACB = 30^0$ , without using trigonometry?

[image]

Comment: Also, not using trigonometry is impossible, it literally is the study of measuring the angles in triangles...

Comment: @Vsotvep, thanks, edited

Comment: Consider the reflection of the triangle across BC.

Comment: @Théophile great idea!! It's so simple in that way! Want to post a short answer so that I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend a point $D$ so that $D$ is colinear to $AB$ and $BD = AB$.

So $\triangle ABC \cong DBC$ by Side ($AB = BD$) Angle ($\angle ABC \cong \angle DBC$ are both right angles) Side $BC=BC$ so $AC=DC$ and $AD = AB+BD = \frac 12 AC + \frac 12 AC= AC$.

So $\triangle ADC$ is equilateral and $\angle ACB=\frac 12 ACD = 60$.  So $\angle ACB = 30$.

===old ====

Then triangle $ABC$ will have angles $60, 60, 60$ so it is an equilateral triangle.  $AD = AC$ and $AB = \frac 12 AC$.

So by Pyth Theorem  $BC^2 + AB^2 = AC^2$ so $BC^2 + (\frac 12 AC)^2 = AC^2$.

Comment: Your idea is correct, but I don't think that's what I wanted to prove,I wanted to prove that $\angle ACB = 30^0$ . After half of the answer, you could conclude that.

Comment: @Muzib So you asked for a proof that $\sin30^\circ=\frac12$ but really wanted a proof that $\arcsin\frac12=30^\circ$? Well, clearly those are equivalent, so you should be happy with a proof of either.

Comment: Oh, I misread your question but...just redo it.  Extend $AB$ to $BD$ and you have an equilateral triangle.  SO the angles are $60-60-60$.

Answer (score 0):

Extend line $AB$ to point $X$ such that $AB$ = $BX$. $AXC$ is an equilateral triangle as $AX = AB + BX = 2AB$. $CB$ is perpendicular to $AX$ so it is the median, so $\angle ACB = \angle {ACX\over2} = \frac {60\deg}2 = 30\deg$